# How could I separate the login from the rest of my application?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a query, I have the `route-outlet`on inside `app.component > main.component> content.component`, the sidebar and footer are in `main.component`, when I charge login this loads all the other component and module, because the `route-outlet` is in `content.component`. How can I isolate the login load separate from main.component to ensure a faster load?

Comment: Just create separate component at the same level as `main.component` and put `route-outlet` in `app.component`?

Comment: exactly that I did not want to get, I wanted to see some other solution

Answer (score 0):

Put your login route before other routes and use custom layout without sidebar/footer.

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: '', component: AppComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    ])
```

Comment: the order of the routes is relevant? I thought that the order did not matter, some link to corroborate?

Comment: Yea, ordering matters. Check this: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/angular-route-ordering/